# How to cluster backup and restore with couchbase Autonomous Operator with Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, helm, couchbase

I need a suggestion over an issue that i am facing currently, I am using  Couchbase Server version 7.1.3 with Couchbase Operator Kubernetes cluster. The problem i am facing is with taking a backup and restoring the backup. The helm chart documentation says to enable backup for version 7 or higher, we need to add the following sections in the helm chart :

```
backups:
  default-backup:
    name: bucket-backup
    strategy: full_incremental
    full:
      schedule: "0 3 * * 0"
    incremental:
      schedule: "0 3 * * 1-6"
    successfulJobsHistoryLimit: 1
    failedJobsHistoryLimit: 3
    backoffLimit: 2
    backupRetention: 24h
    logRetention: 24h
    size: 3Gi

backuprestores:
  default-restore:
    name: bucket-restore
    backup: bucket-backup
    repo: bucket-backup-repo
    start:
      str: oldest
    end:
      str: latest
    backoffLimit: 2
    logRetention: 24h
```

But the issue is that it is not working although it has created the cron job in the k8s cluster, which we can find in the dashboard. Also in the Couchbase server  panel under the backup menu we see this error:

```
The backup interface is only available on Couchbase clusters running the backup service. No Backup nodes were found on this cluster.
```

Where as in the helm chart for version 7 it does not support a backup service to be configured. Also backup files are not created in the volume/PVC which are created by the backup and restore segment. Even if we trigger the cronjob manually from the k8s cluster dashboard, its not generating backups. Any idea guys ? need a help badly here . Thanks